# Rails 3.1 - Create Multiple records to then edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a situation where I want a user to specify the number of records they want to create, have the app then create these blank entries in database and then be presented with an 'edit' view to populate them with their data. I know this is probably bad practice but can anyone give some guidance on how to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to create blank record on the database? You can do like this :

- The user choose the number of new record he wants then, he submits
- You display the creation form X times
- On general submit, you submit each form to your create action

I don't know if you know phpmyadmin, but they do the same.

Comment: This is how it's currently working. The reason I need the blank records it to maintain ordering on validation, if there's a validation error, then the records (in the form) are returned in a different order to they were input.

Comment: You can order by an extra field, no?

Comment: It seems not, only on edit once the records exist in the database

Comment: You can't add an extra field? You put the value in an input hidden in your form, si it will keep the order.

Answer (score 0):

A better approach is to create x numbers of new objects (ex. Post.new) in a loop/partial configuration.  Doing a Post.new creates a new instance of the appropriate db row, but it stores that information in memory and doesn't create that object in the db until you issue the Post.save command.  These virtual database fields have all of the appropriate columns so you will be able to pass them to an edit form and everything should work.  The only thing that it's missing is an id which will be assigned to it after you save.

Comment: I think i'm doing something like that with `@no_tracks = params[:no_tracks].to_i
         @no_tracks.times do
           track = @release.tracks.build
           1.times { track.artists.build }`